# Ace editor's setAnnotations won't stay permanent

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have trouble getting my annotation to stay. See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c8k45yw1/5/

What you will see is line 2, which I set manually, will have "X" mark appear for half a second before it disappear. Thoughts?

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/chrome");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
//editor.session.setBreakpoint(2);
editor.getSession().setAnnotations([{
  row: 1,
  column: 0,
  text: "Strange error",
  type: "error" // also warning and information
}]);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Syntax checker in ace uses same setAnnotations api, and clears old anotations.
You can disable it with `editor.session.setOption("useWorker", false)`

Comment: Thanks! Should have thought of that. Nice catch!

Comment: Annotations aren't staying permanent even after setting useWorker to false. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: @PrinceGautham please create a page demonstrating the issue

Comment: **update 2018**: I don't know why but for me it doesn't work with typescript 2.3.2 and ace 1.2.0. TS throws *Property 'setOption' does not exist on type 'IEditSession'* error). I think that it works with  `editor.setOption("useWorker", false);` too. According to the [doc](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Configuring-Ace) : "editor.setOption will also modify options of editor.session..." .

Comment: You can workaround the typescript issue with some "any" types..  But I tried all the different ways (there are many, including passing useWorker via options props), but none of them work as of 2019-07-04.  The annotations just keep disappearing.  Markers worked just fine.